# DIY: automate cloning of Xen VMs, gold templete?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, xen, automation

looking for DIY way without commercial tools like XenServer LabManager product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the libvirt based tools, virt-clone can copy them without issue and if you need to code something there are libvirt code for a lot of languages. I use the perl bindings for an inhouse project and they are quite solid.

Comment: does libvirt support Xen, please suggest any tools that you are aware of

Comment: yes libvirt supports Xen, KVM, VMWare and Virtualbox - its pretty powerful. Libvirt's frequently used tools are: virt-clone, virsh, virt-install, and virt-manage which is a GUI that allows you to do all of this.

Comment: thanks, correction virt-manager is the GUI not virt-manage